# OdbcDataAdapter Batch update not working

Tags: asp.net, .net, ado.net, odbc

I am trying to perform a batch update in a .NET console application using OdbcDataAdapter by setting UpdateBatchSize:

```
 OdbcDataAdapter da = new OdbcDataAdapter();
 da.UpdateBatchSize = 100;
```

Trying to set UpdateBatchsize property throws following error:

**set_UpdateBatchSize(Int32 value)  Specified method is not supported.**

If I set the UpdateBatchsize value to 1, then it works fine. Does OdbcDataAdapter support batch updates?

Here is [msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kbbwt18a%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to perform batch updates with DataAdapter

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the decompiled code from the DbDataAdapter class:

```
public virtual int UpdateBatchSize
{
  get
  {
    return 1;
  }
  set
  {
    if (1 != value)
      throw ADP.NotSupported();
  }
}
```

The OdbcDataAdapter class does not override it. SqlDataAdapter does this. So, you may conclude that this feature is not supported in OdbcDataAdapter.

Comment: Thanks Gosha for looking into this